# Rewrite rule include paths with slashes not working

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an old website and I want to upgrade it and let it use .htaccess Rewrite rules for search engines, for example, let's say that I have this rule in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^category/electric category.php?type=8
```

this will work without any problems but when the page loaded no images will appear and no css is applied, after I did some search on the internet I found that this problem because of the URL being like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/category/electric
```

and I found the solution but it will take a lot of time to apply it, I found that if I put the full url in each element that require paths like JS, CSS, images, ...... files every thing will be OK like this

```
<img src="images/image.png" width="100" height="100" alt="" />
```

to

```
<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/image.png" width="100" height="100" alt="" />
```

but this will take time as I said so is there any way to cover this problem with any solution.

and sorry for bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the full URL *path* to the image, like this:

```
<img src="/images/image.png" width="100" height="100" alt="" />
```

Note the `/` in front of `images`: that makes the path relative to the document root, not to the current directory.

Another option is to add a [`<base>` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4) into the `<head>` of your pages, like this:

```
<base href="http://www.mywebsite.com/" />
```

This will make all relative URLs on the page act as if it was located at `http://www.mywebsite.com/`.

Unfortunately, both of these solution do require editing the HTML.  HTTP/1.1 does define a [`Content-Location` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.14) which is *supposed* to act like the `<base>` tag in HTML, but browser support for it seems to be limited.  (For example, Mozilla seems to have [decided not to support it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109553) because it would break too many existing sites.)  Apparently, some versions of the HTTP spec also had a `Content-Base` header, but it was also poorly supported and was later [removed from the standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.6.3).

Yet another option, of course, is to *make* `images/image.png` work even if prefixed with `category/`.  The following rewrite rule should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^category/images/(.*) images/$1  [L,R=permanent]
```

(An internal redirect should also work, but may result in browsers requesting the images twice because they don't realize they're the same.  If the images are very small, it might still be more efficient.)

Comment: Those are both good ideas, but they also both require the OP to edit all of their HTML files; I believe the whole thing they were looking for was a solution that didn't require all that (and just involved modifying the .htaccess).

Comment: The only solution I can think of that doesn't require editing the HTML is to rewrite the image URLs back when they're requested.  I've added that to my answer, and also mentioned one non-solution (the poorly supported `Content-Location` HTTP header).

Comment: Only use base as a last resort. As all relative links might break.

Comment: @Gerben: In this case, the OP already broke all his relative links.  Using `<base>` could fix them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a rewrite rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^.*category/electric category.php?type=8
```

Note the extra ".*" in the beginning; that's a wildcard match, which means it should allow any URL, as long as it ends with category/electric...

Comment: How is that going to help the OP?

Comment: Their problem is (or at least seems to be) that their rewrite rule regexp isn't matching URLs that come in with stuff in the front.  So, my theory is that by modifying the regex to match paths with anything in front of them, it will fix things.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^.+(/images/.*)$ $1 [R=301]
```

Redirects example.com/category/images/example.jpg to example.com/images/example.jpg

Not ideal as it requires an extra http request for every image, but there is not other way other than changing the html.